# Floor and ceil function in python

Tags: python

I want to round up a float value to an integer in **python** to multiple of five. say **3.6 to 10** or **21.3 to 25**

Comment: shouldn't `3.6` become `5`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get more help more quickly if you post your attempt. Users don't like writing code for you, but will readily help you fix something.

Answer (score 3):

I would divide it by 5, round it up and then multiply by 5:

```
import math
result = math.ceil(21.3 / 5) * 5
```